# Spy on function that's called on click event

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon, chai, karma-mocha

What am I doing wrong? Trying to spy on a function that get's called on the elements click event but the test always returns false.

spec:

```
describe('button', function() {
  before(function() {
    this.spy = sinon.spy(window, 'testMethod');
  });

  it('Should call testMethod', function() {
    $('#testBtn').click();

    expect(this.spy.called).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

js:

```
$('#testBtn').on('click', testMethod);

function testMethod() {
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is due to the fact that this line:

```
$('#testBtn').on('click', testMethod);
```

grabs a reference to `testMethod` before the spy is set. So it grabs a reference to the original function, not the spy, and then it does not matter that you set a spy on `window.testMethod` because the function called on a click event is always going to be the original `testMethod`. You have a few options to get your test to work:

1. Run `$('#testBtn').on('click', testMethod);` *after* you set the spy. For instance, you could put it in your `before` hook.
2. Change `$('#testBtn').on('click', testMethod);` to `$('#testBtn').on('click', function () { testMethod(); });`. The anonymous function will grab a new reference to `testMethod` every time a click event is handled. So it will grab a reference to the spy, once you set it.

I've tested what I'm saying here by creating a test that replicates your code and using the two fixes above.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
expect(this.spy).to.have.been.called();
```

instead of

```
expect(this.spy.called).to.equal(true);
```

Comment: No, that's not the solution. See my answer. `expect(this.spy).to.have.been.called` (no parentheses: it is not a function call; see the documentation for it) is just a different way to write `expect(this.spy.called).to.equal(true);` The two are functionally equivalent: they will fail in the same situations and pass in the same situations.

Comment: Whoops! I added the parenthesis by mistake. Interesting ... didn't know the two were equivalent.